# No primary or single public constructor found for interface com.filenet.api.core.ObjectStore - and no default constructor found either

Tags: spring-boot, controller, filenet-p8, idbobjectstore

This is my controller -

```
@GetMapping("/dps/{documentName}")
@ResponseBody
public Document findAccountDetails(ObjectStore os, @PathVariable String documentName) {
    return myService.fetchDocById(os, documentName); 
}
```

and

`ObjectStore` is an interface present in this package -

```
com.filenet.api.core.ObjectStore
```

Comment: Maybe you need to write your own argument resolver for this `ObjectStore` interface, take a look at: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder#1-custom-argument-resolver

Comment: There are many methods in ObjectStore interface and I am not sure for which method I need to give the implementation